# Convert list with numeric and string variables to dataframe in R

Tags: r, list

I am wondering how I can convert a list with both numeric and string variables to a dataframe:

For example:

```
aa<-c("a","b","b","b","d")
bb<-c("Yes","No","No","Yes","Yes")
cc<-c(1,2,4,4,3)

x<-list(aa=aa,bb=bb,cc=cc)
```

How can I convert x to a dataframe, such that when I call x I get:

```
  aa  bb cc
1  a Yes  1
2  b  No  2
3  b  No  4
4  b Yes  4
5  d Yes  3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `x<-as.data.frame(x)`.

Updated based on @Frank's good below, if you want to avoid converting characters to factors do

`x<-as.data.frame(x, StringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: Just a note about column classes.  The above solution will convert the character vectors to factor, by default. A way to prevent this, is to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` like so `data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 3):

With large data in a list, it's recommended to change the data "in place".

For reference, see Simon Urbanek's answer here: [Quickly reading very large tables as dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r/13965103#13965103)

```
attr(x, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(unique(lengths(x)))
class(x) <- "data.frame"
x
#   aa  bb cc
# 1  a Yes  1
# 2  b  No  2
# 3  b  No  4
# 4  b Yes  4
# 5  d Yes  3
```

This has two major advantages over `as.data.frame` One is that it avoids copying the object `x`. The other is that it keeps the column classes in line with the list classes (see the following). With `as.data.frame`, character classes would be converted to factors.

```
sapply(x, class)
#          aa          bb          cc 
# "character" "character"   "numeric"
```

Comment: Can you always just assign a class like that? That's really nice.

Comment: If you mean with `class(x) <- ...`, yes. Although it's a bit more technical than that (with `attributes` and things).  `?class` has some good info on it. I know that this works really well with lists.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` would also have a `class` of `data.frame`, so you can make use of the efficient `setDT` function:

```
x <- list(aa = aa, bb = bb, cc = cc)

library(data.table)
setDT(x)
is.data.frame(x)
# [1] TRUE
str(x)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ aa: chr  "a" "b" "b" "b" ...
#  $ bb: chr  "Yes" "No" "No" "Yes" ...
#  $ cc: num  1 2 4 4 3
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> x = data.frame(aa,bb,cc)
> x
  aa  bb cc
1  a Yes  1
2  b  No  2
3  b  No  4
4  b Yes  4
5  d Yes  3
> 
> str(x)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ aa: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","d": 1 2 2 2 3
 $ bb: Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 1 1 2 2
 $ cc: num  1 2 4 4 3
>
```

or:

```
> x = data.frame(aa,bb,cc, stringsAsFactors=F)
> x
  aa  bb cc
1  a Yes  1
2  b  No  2
3  b  No  4
4  b Yes  4
5  d Yes  3
> str(x)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ aa: chr  "a" "b" "b" "b" ...
 $ bb: chr  "Yes" "No" "No" "Yes" ...
 $ cc: num  1 2 4 4 3
>
```

Comment: I think this is missing the point of the "convert a list" part of the question....